# Find the volume under the surface

Tags: multivariable-calculus, integration, volume

Find the volume under the surface $z=f(x,y)$ over the rectangle R, where $f(x,y)=x^4+xy+y^3$ and $R=[1,2]\times[0,2]$

Comment: ...please...? Some ideas, self work...?

Comment: As @DonAntonio said, it would be very helpful to know what you understand and don't understand about this problem. What have you tried? Is this similar to anything you've seen before? Where are you having problems? This will be helpful when we craft our answers.

Comment: I know its a double integral over the region but i am confused on how to set it up. I have V=∬_{D}(x⁴+xy+y³)dxdy so far

Answer (score 1):

With your comment, you're most of the way along to a solution. You correctly realize that this problem is to find
$$
\int\int f(x, y)\,dx\,dy
$$
over the domain defined by (I presume)  $1\le x\le 2, 0\le y\le 2$. With this in mind, what bounds do you have for the innermost integral (the $x$ part) and what bounds do you have for the outer integral (the $y$ part)? In other words, what will $a, b, c, d$ be in
$$
\int_a^b\int_c^d f(x, y)\,dx\,dy
$$
Once you've set these values, the integral should be easy. The inner one will evaluate to sone function involving just $y$ and integrating that with respect to $y$ will give you the number you want.

Comment: Thanks you helped a lot. I ended up with this work. I dont know to post my comment with line breaks so i put commas to separate lines

Comment: V=∫_{a}^{b}∫_{c}^{d}f(x,y)dxdy,
V=∫₀²∫₁²(x⁴+xy+y³)dxdy,
=∫₀²(((x⁵)/5)+((x²y)/2)+xy³+C|₀²),
=∫₀²(y³+((3y)/2)+((31)/5))= ((97)/5),
=((y⁴)/4)+((3y²)/4)+((31y)/5)+C|₀²,
=((97)/5)= 19. 4 units³,

Comment: @R3alAli Quite correct. Good job.